# Connect two buttons to same callback function two arguments

Tags: python, qt, callback, pyqt, signals

I have two buttons, which the user can click and will open a FileDiagloag to select a file. I need the user to select two files but I want one function to handle both button calls. So in my **init** I have:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.Button_SelectJoinFiles_1, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.SelectLogFileToJoin(1))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.Button_SelectJoinFiles_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.SelectLogFileToJoin(2))
```

And the function is basically something like:

```
def SelectLogFileToJoin(self, ButtonNum):
        if(ButtonNum==1):
        ......
        if(ButtonNum==2)
        .....
```

But this doesn't work because when I start the program it start by giving me a file select dialog.

Could someone please tell me how to handle passing an argument to a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is you are passing the value returned by the function, not the function itself. To do what you want, you will want to use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a new function with pre-filled arguments:

```
from functools import partial

...

QtCore.QObject.connect(..., partial(self.SelectLogFileToJoin, 1))
```

Comment: `partial` is overkill in this case. Closure will be quite enough :) `connect(..., lambda: self.SelectLogFileToJoin(1))`

Comment: @astynax Overkill? Using a lambda is a less clear way of reinventing the wheel to do what partial is designed to do.

Comment: You are recommending to partially apply the function with one argument. :) `partial` is good for partial applying of function with many (keyword)arguments. And it has significantly lesser efficiency, than lambda. lambda-functions are good candidates for callbacks. And my lambda-closure looks pretty clean (IMHO).

Comment: *good for*? Why not with one argument? Efficiency really isn't an issue - in my tests the difference is 0.03 usec *in favour of partial* - in any case, it is essentially nothing, and besides, there is no point in premature optimisation. `partial()` is there for a reason, it makes sense to use it.

Comment: May be I just wont to use lambdas in my practice :) This is my FP-way

Comment: @Lattyware, astynax Thank you both for your comments. I'm new to Python and have no experience with partial and lambda. I will try both of these.